# How to pass a geolocation value to a propertie on polymer app

Tags: javascript, polymer

i'm working on a weather app with polymer v1. So i made a custom element called weather-app, i use iron-ajax to make a request for weather data but i can't pass the value for longitude and latitude to computed property to make a request based on current location. Can anyone give me a hand please? thanks in advance.

Edit: Updated code

```
<link rel="import" href="..\..\bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="weather-app">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <iron-ajax
            auto
            url='[[apiUrl]]'
            params='[[_computeParams(key, latitude, longitude, days)]]'
            handle-as="json"
            on-response="handleResponse"
            last-response={{ajaxDataResponse}}
            debounce-duration="300"></iron-ajax>
    <content>
    </content>
  </template>
  <script>
  (function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'weather-app',

      properties: {

        apiUrl: {
          type: String,
          value: 'http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.json'
        },

        key: {
          type: Number,
          readOnly: true,
          value: '0742801303e94a37a2d35509150000'
        },

        latitude: {
          type: Number,
          notify: true,
          value: ''
        },

        longitude: {
          type: Number,
          notify: true,
          value: ''
        },

        days: {
          type: Number,
          value: '7'
        }
      },

      created: function(){

        function getLocation(){

          var geoOptions = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 30000,
            maximumAge: 27000
          };

          function geoSuccess(position){
            console.log(position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude);

            this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;

            return this.latitude + ',' + this.longitude;
          }

          function geoError(){
            console.log('error');
          }

          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError, geoOptions);

        }

        getLocation();

      },

      _computeParams: function(key, latitude, longitude, days){
        return {
          key: key,
          q: latitude + ',' + longitude,
          days: days
        };
      },

      handleResponse: function(){
        console.log('handleResponse');
      }
    });
  })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Rather than passing it into the `_computeParams` function, you can access the properties by doing `this.PROPNAME` for instance: `this.key`, `this.days` etc.

Comment: thanks for your comment Ben, is there any wrong with computed functions? i think i don't understand what do you want to mean. Should i use this.PROPNAME? on iron-ajax? because i tried it, just to see what happens and it didn't work. I think computed function it's useful in this case to make an ajax request to get the data i need. I'm sorry if i'm clumsy, but i'm a beginner.

Comment: See [here](https://gist.github.com/benhjt/92d4a1aa1f5fe269e72f) for a code example.

Comment: Now i understand what do you want to mean, but it did not work. Apparently the values does not pass to the params because the response was "API key is invalid or not provided"  but when i tried with computed function just fail on get the latitude and longitude values. (It sends the key and days without problem). I guess the problem is on geoSuccess function and how return the values for latitude and longitude and how property have access to these values. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is in the current lack of ability of the parent to notify the child. This is due to the notify property being disabled.

```
latitude: {
  type: Number,
  notify: true,
  value: ''
},

longitude: {
  type: Number,
  notify: true,
  value: ''
},
```

Then in your geosuccess you need to use the "set" method of the element in order for polymer to properly notify other elements of the change.

```
  function geoSuccess(position){
    console.log(position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude);

    this.set('latitude', position.coords.latitude);
    this.set('longitude', position.coords.longitude);

    return this.latitude + ',' + this.longitude;
  }
```

As a bonus, when using computation functions simply use the [[ ]] notation. It won't give the app a huge boost, but it is better for performance.

Also, having the observer for _getCoordinates seems to lead me to believe that this function *could* be infinitely recursive if the position changes slightly each time, given that it sets the location variables again and again each call. Use the created/ready/attach methods to initialize the element with the geolocation position. Set the position. The observer you have in place is probably not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Brandon. I tried all you said:
1.- Enable notify property
2.- Delete the observer
3.- Put the function inside of Created method
4.- Use This.set to pass value to property but in this step i have a problem that it say "Uncaught TypeError: this.set is not a function"

I think i'm not returning the values on the right way so the properties can have access to the values from latitude and longitude from geoSuccess function. Anyway, i'm not pretty sure of that. But, I will searching on internet for more information until i find the answer or somebody can help me.